# Passing a method as a reference with default parameters

Tags: kotlin, lambda, reference, default-arguments

I've a class where I'm passing a static method `A` of another class to a method `M` with reference. The method `A` has a default argument however due to the method signature of the method `M`, it's forcing me to provide all the arguments even the default argument.

I don't want to pass the default argument since some classes with method `A` don't have/require the argument that's setup as default argument in method `A` of all the classes.

```
class MyClass1 : BaseClass {

  companion object {
       fun A(obj1 : Type1, obj2 : Type2, obj3 : Type3? = null) { //implementation }
  }
}

class MyClass2 : BaseClass {

  companion object {
       fun A(obj1 : Type1, obj2 : Type2) { //implementation }
  }
}

class ClassX {

    fun M(obj1 : Type1, obj2: Type2, obj3 : Type3? = null, A : (Type1, Type2, Type3) -> TypeX) {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

MyClass1 method `A` can take all the arguments however Since MyClass2 doesn't have obj3 in its method A, I can't pass Method A as a reference to this method M anymore.

Is there a way to set default argument for method reference in Method `M`?

Answer (score 2):

No, functional parameters cannot be defined as having default parameter values. They must be fully concrete. When you pass `MyClass1::A` to this function, it is not passing a function that has default parameters, but rather it is selecting the implicit, specific overload of `A` that fits the signature.